# Is it possible to rename a customizer control heading?

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

So far I couldn't figure out how to rename a customizer control. I can rename sections, but cannot find a way to controls. I would like to rename the default **Tagline** control to **Site Description**.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

```
$wp_customize->get_control('blogdescription')->label = esc_html__( 'Site Description', 'textdomain' );
```